# is there any library function for word counting in c#..?

Tags: c#

I am wondering is there any functions in c# that helps to count number of words,sentences in a file...?

Now I used the following code is it efficient/error free?

```
string[] words=datafromfile.Split(' ');
int numberofwords=words.GetUpperBound(0)
```

Thank you

Comment: Looks like homework.  do numbers count as words.  What about repeated spaces.

Comment: Actually I used System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(datafromfile, " {2,}", " "); to replace the multiple spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`RegEx.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split.aspx) using the [word boundary `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're not considering new lines as word boundaries. Full stop is also a word boundary. You should use regex for this. It has \b

Use `int words = Regex.Split(yourText, "\b").Length`

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box, but you can look at [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/word-count).